# What does = 0 mean in PATINDEX?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The code should accept nicknames containing the characters a-z A-Z 0-9 _ - '

```sql
IF PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9_-']%' , @nickname) = 0
RETURN 1;
```

Comment: Note that that statement isn't valid either, as the single quote (`'`) inside the string literal isn't properly escaped (which can easily be seen from the syntax highlighting).

Comment: Fyi, the `^` in the pattern excludes the character ranges. So it'll return 0 when the string doesn't contain characters that are not in those ranges.

Answer (score 3):

From the first line of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on `PATINDEX`:

> Returns the starting position of the first occurrence of a pattern in a specified expression, **or zeros if the pattern is not found**, on all valid text and character data types.

The documentation should *always* be your first port of call if you don't understand what a function does, or what the value(s) it returns represent.